# Indecomposable representation of central elements have single eigenvalue

Tags: representation-theory

I was working through Etingof's notes on representation theory, but quickly ran into a stumbling block on the following problem.

Let $A$ be an algebra, $z \in Z(A)$ and V an indecomposable finite dimensional representation. Show that $\rho(z)$ has only one eigenvalue.

I have the feeling that the right way to go about this is to demonstrate that $\rho(z)$ has only one Jordan block. I know the fact that $\rho(z)$ commutes with every $\rho(a), a \in A$ means that $\rho(z)$ is an intertwining operator, but I'm not really sure how to use this to demonstrate that there is only one Jordan block, or where the indecomposable hypothesis comes into play.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that $A$ is a $k$-algebra and $V$ is a $k$-vector space, where $k$ is a field. Suppose that $\rho(z)$ has more than one eigenvalues you can write the Jordan decomposition $V=\oplus ker(\rho(z)-c_i)^{n_i}$ where $c_i$ is an eigenvalue of $\rho(z)$, the space $ker(\rho(z)-c_i)^{n_i}$ are submodules.